# Ignore part of file in git when using on 2 different computers (python)

Tags: python, git

I am using a python program on 2 different computers.

- On computer 1 some path (e.g., to an image or something), used by the program, is, say, a/b/
- On computer 2, the equivalent path is different, say, b/a/ (the image, e.g., is in a different folder)

When I want to run the script on computer 1 I pull the code and set the path to a/b/. Then I make changes and push.

Then I go to computer 2 and pull. Now the path is a/b/ but actually I want the pull to **not** change the path (all the rest should change though of course).

**Q1:**
Is there a way to automatically do this (prevent the changes in the path)? Also I keep getting merge conflicts just due to the path being different.

**Q2:** I might not even be doing this in an optimal way, how do people do this? My procedure could be wrong causing these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute paths that depend on your specific computer do not belong in version control. A good solution would be to have your program read an environment variable and use it as the path. Make sure to set a sensible default if the environment variable is unset.